# Django - Unable to import model

Tags: django, django-models, import

Here is the problem. I just pushed my code online but for some reason it doesn't work.

I keep getting unable to import model error even though locally it works just fine.

I used south to run the --auto and then I updated the app.

The tables associated to those models are in my DB and all....

Here is my model code:

```
class MemberEligibility(models.Model):

     member = models.OneToOneField(Member)
     eligibility = models.IntegerField(editable=False,default=0)
     verified_by = models.ForeignKey(Member,related_name='verified_by',blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

     class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Member Eligibility")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Members Eligibility")

     def is_eligible(self):
         if self.eligibility == 2:
             return True
         else:
             return False
```

Note Member is part of the same app and same models.py file

But for some reason, I am unable to import it and I am sure there is no circular import because it works just fine locally.

**EDIT:**

I am getting this error:

> cannot import name MemberEligibility

And here is how I import the in my views models:
from acpkinballmanagemembers(app name).models import Member, MemberEligibility

**EDIT 2:**

I tried lazy relationship also with `Member = models.OneToOneField('Member')` and `verfied_by = models.ForeignKey('Member')`

Still not working...

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: Are you doing: 'myproject.app.models import Member, MemberEligibility' ? Make sure you have the correct project name.

Comment: @DanielRoseman cannot import name MemberEligibility

Comment: @AAA Well I import it with: 'app.models import Member, MemberEligibility'.

Comment: Depending on your project directory, you may need to import the project name. What's the name of the entire project? Use the above code and try that with your project name. FYI, your project directory could be the parent folder of your app folder.

Comment: @AAA, why is my Member model loading without any problem though? Sorry, I am still kinda new to Django. I am trying to understand.... if that's the case shoudn't Member be sending the error before the MemberEligibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add the project name to the Python path. Either in your wsgi.py file:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/full/path/to/project/base')
```

or in your Apache configuration:

```
WSGIPythonPath /full/path/to/project/base
```

Comment: Well you kinda answered my question.... I had the wrong path. I had my path to my production directory and not my preprod directory. I am so sorry, totally forgot about it.